# How can i make editable text layer psd file using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, layer, psd

i have problems, that i cant make a text layer.
I tried pango (-draw text), label and it always make a image layer.
Also i tried to attach *.tif file with text layers, but it make image layer from it.

my code is :

```
convert ( -page +10+10 -label "label1" -pointsize 30 -font Arial -draw "text 25,60 'Magick'" -channel RGBA -fill red ) ( -page +0+0 -label "label1" 1.jpg -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB ) ( -page +0+0 -label "label2" 2.jpg -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB ) ( -page +0+0 -label "label3" 3.gif -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB ) ( -clone 0-5 -background none -flatten ) -alpha On -reverse -extent 750x750 -insert 0 "out.psd"
```

ImageMagick version 6.8.9 x64 windows

Comment: You cannot use ImageMagick to create text layers. It will always convert text to pixels.